# How to call a function in mainwindow from secondwindow(widget) with a button

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am able to call a variable (result) into second window(widget) from MainWindow with using below code:

MainWindow:

```
def Two_items_show(self):
    self.Two_Items = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    self.ui = Ui_Two_Items(self.result)
    self.ui.setupUi(self.Two_Items)
    self.Two_Items.show()
```

Second Window:

```
class Ui_Two_Items(object):
    def __init__(self, result = ''):
        self.result = result
```

The Question is: 
Mainwindow has a function, and second window has a push button, I want to  call that function from second window with the push button.

Second Window:

```
self.btn.clicked.connect(self.change)

def change(self):
    self.delete_item()
```

MainWindow:

```
 def delete_item(self):
    ...
    ...
```

If it is possible please let me know the solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may do is to add the parent in the **init** method of your window as:

```
def __init__(self, result=None, parent=None)
```

You would call your MainWindow function as:

```
def change(self):
    parent.delete_item()
```

And to open your second window from the Main,

```
win = UI_Two_Items(result=xx,parent=self)
```

Hope it works for you.